# How to link to static library?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I have an executable that links to a static library I build and another library that is provided to me already built.

I'm trying to get cmake to link to it but I always get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lsrc/thislibrary/libthislibrary.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [MyExecutable] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DocumentParserTests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

These are my build instructions:

```
add_executable(MyExecutable tests/MyExecutable.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable statictests)
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable myownlib)
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable src/thislibrary/libthislibrary.a)
```

Both `statictests` and `myownlib` build flawlessly.

Comment: did u try? `use -v to see invocation` what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake is running the link command from a different working directory than you expect.  Instead of using bare relative paths in a CMakeLists.txt file, use the special variables `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`, `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, etc.

For a quick cheat-sheet of the meanings of these, see http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables, or see the CMake documentation.

In your case, I suspect the correct path location is this:

```
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/thislibrary/libthislibrary.a)
```